# How to use OO in Lua Corona Labs? Unable to index error

Tags: lua, coronasdk

Im using the Corona SDK for developing games and created a new project that comes with a main.lua file, but wanted to add other seperate files such as player.lua so i could do object oriented.

My goal is to create a player from the main and i did some research on how that can be done.
[a link to lua tutorial](http://www.troubleshooters.com/codecorn/lua/luaoop.htm)

Here is my code for those files:

player.lua :

```
Player = {}

Player.new = function(name, id)

    local self = {}
    name = name or "player"
    id = id or 0

    self.getName = function() return name end
    self.getId = function() return id end

    end
return self
```

main.lua :

```
local Player = require("scripts.player")

player1 = Player.new("Player1", 1)
print(player1.getName())
```

Im expecting a print in the console.  The error says 'unable to index local Player (a boolean value) stack traceback' in main.lua

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue is that you have the return statement for constructor in the wrong place. It should be inside the constructor rather than outside:

```lua
Player = {}

Player.new = function(name, id)
    local self = {}
    name = name or "player"
    id = id or 0

    self.getName = function() return name end
    self.getId = function() return id end

    return self
end
```

Indenting your code consistently will help you see such problems straight away. I suggest always having `end` indented at the same level as the opening of the block (no matter if it is a `function`, `for`, `do` or whatever else).

After solving this issue you have the problem mentioned by Nifim - you need to take care of shadowing the `Player`. The simplest solution would be to add a return statement in the end of the *player.lua*:

```
Player = {}

-- `Player.new` and so on...

return Player
```

You could also make the `Player` local if you want. It is not needed but it might be desired.

**Or** you could remove the assignment from the *main.lua*:

```
require("scripts.player")
local player = Player.new()
```

Answer (score 3):

You do not return your player lib in `player.lua`. so when you call

```
local Player = require("scripts.player")
```

You shade the global variable `Player` created in `player.lua` with the result of require which is `true`.

> References on Require: https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#6.3

---

You have 2 choices to correct this issue.

Option 1)
change `player.lua`

```
local Player = {}

Player.new = function(name, id)

    local self = {}
    name = name or "player"
    id = id or 0

    self.getName = function() return name end
    self.getId = function() return id end

    return self
end

return Player
```

**OR** Option 2) Change `main.lua`

```
require("scripts.player")

player1 = Player.new("Player1", 1)
print(player1.getName())
```

Option one follows more modern Lua module conventions, but either option will resolve your issue.

Comment: I went with option 1 so i changed only player.lua and kept everything else the same in main.lua, it says it cant load the scripts.player module because its expecting an '=' sign in main.lua where the require line is and there is an '=' sign already there.  When i try option 2 changing only main.lua, i get the unable to index error global player1 is a nil value.  Could you please provide any further suggestions?

Comment: Oh looks like i typoed `local` as `Local` , if you copied it that maybe an issue you are seeing.

Comment: even if i use a lower case local it gives me an <eof> expected near return error in main.lua .  the syntax is so close but where is the problem at?  Remember this is Corona Labs game development using Lua that shouldn't change anything